# Syncing md-optgroup and md-options in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

The below is working like a charm, except when we have duplicate names
    in one of the values of md-optgroup (we are displaying and then filtering the groups by name).
    Is there a way I can avoid this?

```
<md-option ng-value></md-option>
   <md-optgroup label = "{{groupName}}" ng-repeat = "groupName in $ctrl.Names">
           <md-option  ng-value="rEntry" ng-repeat="rEntry in $ctrl.rList | filter: {rName: groupName} ">{{ $ctrl.formattedREntry(rEntry) }}</md-option>
    </md-optgroup>
```

UPDATE: Just a detail, seems that one of the values that fall within a particular groupName is falling into another group; the group names only defer by the last character: one is "Role Name 1" the other is "Role Name".

Comment: Can you make a codepen or fiddle ?

Answer (score 1):

am not familiar with `angular-material` but i understood you problem wich is duplicated values that appears to make problems  in the filter you could actually use the Unique filter from AngularUI

```
<md-option ng-value></md-option>
<md-optgroup label = "{{groupName}}" ng-repeat = "groupName in $ctrl.Names">
       <md-option  ng-value="rEntry" ng-repeat="rEntry in $ctrl.rList | filter: {rName: groupName} | unique:'groupName'"">{{ $ctrl.formattedREntry(rEntry) }}</md-option>
</md-optgroup>
```